# Lindo syntax error for division

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, lindo

I have tried adding parenthesis to the code but lindo gives an error stating that its a variable. According to lindo documentation "(" should be accepted as a parenthesis but this does not occur. Removing the parenthesis causes the code to terminate as soon as it encounters the division symbol. Does anybody know what I'm missing in my code? (error occurs on the 4th, 5th and 6th line of code).

```
min     Y1 + Y2 + Y3 + Y4 + Y5 + Y6
ST
        Y1 + Y2 + Y3 + Y4 + Y5 + Y6 >= 1

5X11 + 10X12 + 2X13 + 5X14 + 4X15 + 4X16 / Y1 <= 10
5X21 + 10X22 + 2X23 + 5X24 + 4X25 + 4X26 / Y2 <= 10
5X31 + 10X32 + 2X33 + 5X34 + 4X35 + 4X36 / Y3 <= 10
```

Comment: I believe Lindo only accepts linear models. Lingo does nonlinear models.

Comment: So I got the answer. Its basically rephrasing this as: 5X11 + 10X12 + 2X13 + 5X14 + 4X15 + 4X16 -10Y1 <= 0 which would make the equation linear.

Comment: Just to be sure: `5X11 + 10X12 + 2X13 + 5X14 + 4X15 + 4X16 / Y1 <= 10` is not the same as `5X11 + 10X12 + 2X13 + 5X14 + 4X15 + 4X16 -10Y1 <= 0`.

Comment: I feel that they should be the same as it’s basically moving variables in the equation